# How to go from AST to backend code?

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree

I'm working on a compiler for a programming language and I have a good representation of the source language in the form of an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST). I tried generating backend code directly by traversing the AST, but that's not working well. In general, think of mapping an AST for a C-like language down to an assembly-like language. I now think that there is some phase that I'm missing to go from the AST to backend code. The problem is that going from the AST to the next representation (say, 3-address code) is rought. It feels like there is a step in between that I'm missing.

```
[source lang] -> [lex/parse]-> [AST] -> [semantic analysis] -> [?] -> [backend code]
```

This is what I've come up with while thinking about it:

1) Transform the AST of the source language to an AST that represents the backend. This means that I would need to have 2 different ASTs. Then, output the backend from the transformed AST.

2) Transform the AST to a different type of data structure, and generated backend code based on this other structure. I'm not sure what this other struct would be.

3) Traverse the AST in a different way (from the way used to pretty print it) to generate the backend code. This is how I tried doing it first but it doesn't seem right; I feels like a hackish way to go about it.

**What are my options go to from AST to backend code?**

Note that I'm not asking what kinds of representations the AST could be turned into, such as 3-address code. For example, I understand that a C addition like so:

```
x = a + b + c
```

could be turned into 3-address like so:

```
t1 = add a, b
t2 = add t1, c
set x, t2
```

I am asking for techniques/guidance/experience on *how* to do it.

To give an example of the type of answer that I'm looking for would be:

Question: What steps can I take to perform semantic analysis on the source lang?

Answer: Parse the language into an AST and traverse the AST to perform the semantic checks.

Comment: Here you ask "*how* to do it" .... in comments to may answer below, you say "Maybe I do need to tansform the AST to some other representation" as if you aren't convinced.  Which is it?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

One can represent the program any way one likes; you can build compilers completely using trees.  The purpose of a representation is to make it easy to collect certain kinds of facts; the representation serves to make collection/processing of those specific facts easier.  Thus one expects the representation of the program to change at different stages of compilation, depending on what the compiler is trying to achieve in that stage.

One typical scheme is to translate programs through these representations to produce final code:

```
 *  ASTs
 *  Triples
 *  Abstract machine instructions
 *  Concrete machine instructions
```

The fact that you don't seem to know this, means you haven't done your homework.  This is pretty well described in compiler books. Go read one.

Comment: I thought that I had made my question abstract enough such that these kinds of answers wouldn't arise. Think of it as though I were asking how to go from AST to triples. I pulled out my Dragon Book and in the code generation chapter, page 513, it talks about triples but not how to get there from an AST.

Comment: I'll edit the post to make it more clear what I'm after. I'm not looking for an explanation that a + b + c should be turned into: t1 = add a, b; t2 = add t1, c; I'm looking for *how* to do it. This is akin to asking of how one goes from source language to semantic analysis: transform the source lang to an AST and perform the analysis on the AST. It's a generality that would work for any source language. I do appreciate that you're trying to help, though.

Comment: Yeah, I did. I also looked at the sections that you mentioned in book (I have the same edition). Unfortunately, those are good answers to a different question.

Comment: You know, maybe my question is just confusing. My basic issue is that outputing code directly from the AST feels like to big of a leap in  transformation. Maybe I'm answering my own question: Maybe I do need to tansform the AST to some other intermediate representation before the output phase.

Comment: Do you understand what "syntax directed translation" is?  Do you understand how it is implemented?

Comment: I am building my AST using syntax directed translation. My goal is to get from the AST to the final output, so I'm passed the SDT phase.

Comment: Mr. Baxter, while discussing this with you, I convinced myself that I'll turn the AST into another representation, and then I'll output code based on that other representation. Unfortunately, I won't be able to use the Visitor pattern on this new repres, since it's not an AST struct. I was hoping to be able to reuse the Visitor pattern to output code, since it works so well for semantic analysis, but I can't use it on the new repres that I chose. I'll see if it's worth giving up the pattern.

Comment: Trees are great for capturing syntax, but are lousy for reasoning about long-distance effects.   A good compiler *needs* to reason about thing that happen far away in the program; thus the use of intermediate representations which are essentially data flow graphs.  Yes, you have to give up the tree-visitor pattern.   You can replace that with a graph-node visitor pattern, if you insist.   ...

Comment: I get the impression you just don't want to read the literature; it tells you why the various representations are important. And you are losing the benefits of understanding the collected wisdom of 50 years of compiler design.  I've done my job.